# I am a non-EU citizen, one of 3 directors of a company in the UK. How can I work in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa

The situation is that I am one of 3 directors of a digital agency set up in the UK. We are a remote team with multiple UK and Europe based clients, and our team is all over the world.

I am not an EU citizen. I would like to go over to the UK to assist with growing the business. The only way I can see this working is if our company applies to be a sponsor, and then sponsors me to work in the UK in a formal position.

1. Is this a viable option?
2. Are there any other options available in this case?

Comment: Welcome to expatriates.SE.  How long do you plan to stay in the UK?

Comment: It *may* make a difference which country your employment contract is based in, and which country you'd be paid in?

Comment: Thanks! I would want to stay there for 1-2 years. Currently I'm employed by the company as the technical lead, although I am also a shareholder/owner.

Comment: Are you employed through the UK office, or through something in your current country?

Comment: Right now I basically "contract" to the UK company at an hourly rate. Another problem is we don't have our own offices, as we all work remotely. We do have a base at a shared workspace in London, however. I am based in South Africa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Capital Amount Required

Unless you have a significant amount of money to invest (more than £200,000), or are sponsored by a venture capital firm, you are unlikely to be able to come to the UK based only on your role as a shareholder/founder of a business.

## Tier 1 Entrepreneur Visa

The [Tier 1 Entrepreneur Visa](https://www.gov.uk/tier-1-entrepreneur/overview) is the primary method of entry for people wanting to come to the UK to set up a business.

There are two investment levels:

1. £50,000 capital - this is primarily for people that are being sponsored by a [registered venture capital firm or similar](https://www.gov.uk/tier-1-entrepreneur/access-to-50000-investment-funds).
2. £200,000 capital - if you are [setting up your own business with private investors](https://www.gov.uk/tier-1-entrepreneur/access-to-200000-investment-funds).

There are quite a few requirements for this visa. You need to be able to speak English, and be [eligible given the UK government points scoring system](https://www.gov.uk/tier-1-entrepreneur/eligibility). You also need to be a company director.

Further, you will need to show savings above and beyond the investment amount, so as to be able to support yourself. The above pages have additional information.

If you are eligible for this visa, you would be able to apply for 3 year residency. The visa can be extended by another 2 years, but only if your business has created [two full time jobs that have existed for at least 12 months](https://www.gov.uk/tier-1-entrepreneur/extend-your-visa).

After 5 years in the country, you would be eligible for Indefinite Leave to Remain (IRL) - which allows you to live in the country permanently.

You can bring family with you (though you need to show additional savings to support them). Your spouse will most likely be able to work.

## Tier 1 Graduate Entrepreneur Visa or Exceptional Talent Visa

If you're setting up your own business, and have a well recognised degree (probably a PhD), you might be eligible for the [Graduate Entrepreneur](https://www.gov.uk/tier-1-graduate-entrepreneur-visa) or [Exceptional Talent](https://www.gov.uk/tier-1-exceptional-talent/overview) visa.

Please note that there are *very* few of these issued per year, and this is quite an unlikely route. Less than 200 exceptional talent visas for technical businesses are issued per year according to [this article](http://www.workpermit.com/news/2014-03-31/uk-will-issue-fewer-than-200-tier-1-exceptional-talent-tech-visas-per-year).

## Ancestry

As you mention you are South African, you might find that you or your spouse are are eligible for an [Ancestry visa](https://www.gov.uk/ancestry-visa/overview). This visa would allow you to live in the UK, set up your own business, or work for any company you wish.

There are numerous complicated rules related to dates of birth and locations of parents/grandparent's births to take into account with the Ancestry visa. Some people find out that they are actually already British Citizens, or eligible for Ancestry.

There is an automated site that attempts to work out your eligibility automatically at [WhatPassport.com](http://www.whatpassport.com/). Please note that registration and your email address required. As the rules change, they will inform you if your eligibility changes.

Please note that I've not used WhatPassport's visa services at all. If you use the site, you should make your own judgement as to whether to use them or not.